# Pandas dataframe change date from int64 to date in datetime

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, int64

I have a dataframe where the date column type is int64. I want to convert that column and its values to datetime.

```
df['datdadat'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datadate'].astype('str'), errors='coerce')
```

[image: conversion with my code in the last column]

As you can see, my code fails when encountering the second row without leading zeroes for the months/days. I tried adding a format already, but when I add it in, even the first one with zeroes fails.

My question would be how to add in the leading zeroes before conversion, or if there is a good way to add a format in while converting it? 
Thx in advance

Comment: So is it 030184 or 300184? I don't know that you can really know whether the date or the month is missing the leading 0...

Comment: @ALollz: `300184` only makes sense if the day comes first. otherwise, the month would have two leading zeros.

Comment: `.astype('str')` makes no sense; I'd suspect the col is `str` in the first place since you can't have an integer `030184`. check @NYCCoder's suggestion, that should work.

Comment: [The dtype realy is int64](https://i.imgur.com/ZBTFaXN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['datdadat'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datdadat'], format='%d%m%y')
print(df)

       datdadat
0 1984-01-30
1 1983-12-30
```

Comment: Read the bit about format codes here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html